# Get activity background color in android API level 8

Tags: android

How to do it?
In API level 17 I used:

```
int color = ((ColorDrawable) activityLayout.getBackground()).getColor();
```

But `ColorDrawable` method `getColor()` added in API level 11 and so I cannot use this method.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may look stupid, but I suggest to draw the `ColorDrawable` over `1 pixel dimension bitmap` and get the pixel color in the bitmap using `bitmap.getPixel(0, 0);`

// Sample Code

```
  ColorDrawable colorDrawable=((ColorDrawable) activityLayout.getBackground());

  Bitmap bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Config.ARGB_4444);
  Canvas canvas= new Canvas(bitmap);
  colorDrawable.draw(canvas);   
  int pix = bitmap.getPixel(0, 0);
  bitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: Do I need to release any resources after obtaining color of a pixel? May be I should delete Bitmap or Canvas object ?

Comment: yeah, you can **recycle** the `Bitmap`, using `bitmap.recycle();`

Comment: This feels so dirty to use... but I'm totally using it. :) I don't see a better option short of reflection (which I avoid if at all possible since you can't trust that the structure has remained the same). I'm always amazed at the simple getters like this that seem to be missing all over the place in lower API levels.

Comment: I found useful the answers here (both get and set) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795920/get-background-color-from-textview-without-using-colordrawable-api-11

Comment: And you think using reflection is better than this?